# How to apply a motion to a model?

Tags: linked-data, motion-capture

Blenders. A newbie is here.
I've been looking for how to apply a motion to a model in Blender, but it's not easy to find. I've been googling and searching on Youtube, but no luck. Here is my process:

1. I created a character with Vroid and exported it as glb file.
2. Imported it into Blender.
3. Used Mixmao

   1. I downloaded a motion from Mixamo and downloaded it as fbx file.
   2. Imported it into Blender.
   3. Then I have no idea how to link them.
4. Used Plask

   1. I created a motion from Plask and downloaded it as glb file.
   2. Imported it into Blender.
   3. Same. I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Just look up some youtube videos like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIP8QibQ7XU or this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHbreglPNGw

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already tried the second method, but it didn't work somehow. And the first one is about animation, so it's kinda off-topic.
I found this one; https://youtu.be/wYrz0U4RApk, and it also didn't work when I tried it at 1:45 in the video. I'm lost.

Comment: Upload your model to Mixamo and let rigging processed there, choose desired motion and download. That is the most easiest and clean way. Adobe also released add-on to automatically rig model that fits mixamos conventions. So easy to assign or switch Actions than. Here also a bit explanation what is happening wrong with current mixamo's bones.  characters https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249651/2214 ... Ignore the descending part. Here is nice add-on introduction, covering also bone issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYqJ7AyEuhc

Comment: I tried it many times, but somehow Mixamo gave me some errors always and haven't succeeded to do it. I don't know why and it's really frustrating. That's why I'm trying a different way.