# From Control-Rig to Standard Bones

Tags: rigging, add-on, conversion

To solve the problem described in the article [*"Fixing Descending Stairs Walk from Mixamo"*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249262/fixing-descending-stairs-walk-from-mixamo), I used the [*Mixamo Control-Rig addon*](https://substance3d.adobe.com/plugins/mixamo-in-blender/). Everything is well fixed.

[image]

In the next step, I am trying to transfer the character to another file. As a result, I get a complete collapse of the system.

[image]

Is there a way to get the character back to standard bones, or is it a one way road?
Blender version 3.1.2.

Comment: ouch! How have you transferred the model?

Comment: Copy Objects (Ctrl+C), then Paste Objects (Ctrl+V). With standard bones, this has always worked.

Comment: Due to the silence of the experts, it becomes clear to me that the reverse conversion by simple methods is impossible in this environment.

Comment: To transfer the rig from one blend file to another I would put everything into a collection (e.g. rig & mesh) and use File > Append ... in the destination file to add the collection & content. It's hard to tell why your rig is messed up. Maybe something got lost when you copy & pasted stuff?

Comment: Through "Append ..." also does not work. Exporting and importing a character through the *.fbx and *.obj formats gives approximately the same results. I already did "Select All" and added all hidden objects to the collection. And already experimented on two characters. It remains only to create a scene in the same file, around this character. Or fix the bug "Descent down the stairs" without this addon. In general, it is strange that such a solid company can not fix this.

Comment: I would like to understand all the same, is this due to my old hardware and pirated programs, or is this a flaw in this addon?

Comment: I would also like an answer to this question. Surely there is a way to convert the rig BACK to standard armature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control rig contains the original armature on a layer (1). Only these bones deform the mesh. So the solution is to export only them.

[image: Export only deformation bones]

Blender 3.6+: `Export Deformation Bones only` is moved to `Data` > `Armature`-section

Comment: That's indeed how it should be done. If the rig is made correctly, only the bones meant to deform are marked as "deform bones", and the export option will do the job for you. If some non-deforming bones are marked as deform bones, you probably should unmark them first.